# unable to build an android phonegap apk

Tags: cordova

I'm using phonegap v6.4.7 with cordova v6.5.0
when using the phonegap command:
phonegap -d build android

I get the following error;
have read all the docs I can get my hands on but I can't find an answer..

```
Error: Error
at Object.module.exports.check_gradle (W:\gap\CameraApp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:90:25)
at GradleBuilder.prepEnv (W:\gap\CameraApp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\GradleBuilder.js:161:23)
at Api.module.exports.run (W:\gap\CameraApp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\build.js:152:20)
at W:\gap\CameraApp\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:345:43
at _fulfilled (W:\gap\CameraApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (W:\gap\CameraApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (W:\gap\CameraApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
at W:\gap\CameraApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
at runSingle (W:\gap\CameraApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
at flush (W:\gap\CameraApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
```

Comment: remove the platform "phonegap platform rm android" then again add "phonegap platform add android" and then try to run.
It will works.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you solve this problem entirely, but maybe this bit of information will point you in the right direction.

First remove the current android platform from phonegap:

```
phonegap platform rm android
```

Then force it to install version 6.2.3 of the android platform:

```
phonegap platform add android@6.2.3
```

Now, instead of "Error: Error", you should see something like this:

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined                                                                             
    at Object.module.exports.check_gradle (C:\nodejs\apps\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:143:19)                  
    at GradleBuilder.prepEnv (C:\nodejs\apps\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\GradleBuilder.js:176:23)                   
    at Api.module.exports.run (C:\nodejs\apps\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\build.js:152:20)                                   
    at C:\nodejs\apps\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:348:43                                                                  
    at _fulfilled (C:\nodejs\apps\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)                                        
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\nodejs\apps\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30)                         
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\nodejs\apps\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)                   
    at C:\nodejs\apps\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44                                                     
    at runSingle (C:\nodejs\apps\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)                                         
    at flush (C:\nodejs\apps\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be a bug in Cordova's Android platform, and I've been unable to get past this issue.

Comment: thank you for help, I tried different workarounds and no joy, so we went the react-native way and that works to perfection and learned react/react-native in the process. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the android platform.

```
phonegap platform rm android
```

and then please add the platform again in the project.

```
phonegap platform add android
```

and then build it again using

```
phonegap build android
```

Comment: did you try this ?

Comment: I gave up when I tried React-native and found it to work perfectly for what I needed. thank you for your help.